# ReactJS: every subsequent react testing library test after first one fails

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm new to React. Somehow only my first test succeeds, and the rest fail. Even if I make the second test same as the first one, it still fails. If I comment out the first test, the second one succeeds, and then the rest fail with component not being found via the `id` and not present in the DOM.

**Here are my tests:**

```
describe('Given SomeComponent component', () => {
    configure({ testIdAttribute: 'id' });

    describe('When trying to render with only id prop set', () => {
        const property = {
            id: '1',
        } as Property;
        render(<SomeComponent prop={property} />);

        it('Should render successfully', () => {
            expect(screen.getAllByTestId('chart-1')).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });

    describe('When trying to render without data prop set', () => {
        const property = {
            id: '1',
            name: 'property of test',
        } as Property;
        render(<SomeComponent prop={property} />);

        it('Should render successfully', () => {
            expect(screen.getAllByTestId('chart-1')).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

Tested component: SomeComponent

```
export interface Prop {
    property: Property;
}

export const SomeComponent = ({ property }: Prop): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <>
            <div id={`chart-${curveProperty.id}`}>haha</div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
describe("Given SomeComponent component", () => {
  configure({ testIdAttribute: "id" });

  it("Should render successfully", () => {
    const property = {
      id: "1",
    } as Property;
    const { rerender } = render(<SomeComponent prop={property} />);
    expect(screen.getAllByTestId("chart-1")).toBeTruthy();

    const newProperty = {
      id: "1",
      name: "property of test",
    } as Property;
    rerender(<SomeComponent prop={newProperty} />);
    expect(screen.getAllByTestId("chart-1")).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure this is what I need as I want to retain my testing structure with strict parent / child definitions... or I cannot do that in react?

Comment: yes you can do that in react, but one thing to note here is that you're using `getAllByTestId` but your `Tested component` doesn't have any `data-testid` attribute

Comment: @DenissM. I suggest you add the whole test inside a platform like `codesandbox` so we could help you better

Comment: you didn't notice this: `configure({ testIdAttribute: 'id' });` it is testing using the `id` param instead

Comment: btw: I tried to use rerender as you suggested, and that didn't work also :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use jest `test` instead of `it` and it started to work just I wanted it to.

Comment: Sounded weird and didn't work for me actually

Answer (score 0):

In case switching from `it` to `test` doesn't work as it didn't for me:

If the `<SomeComponent/>` is slightly more complex there could be things still happening at the moment you call `getAllByTestId`. In my case - switching to the `findAllByTestId` did the job and all tests are passing as expected.